# Get specific twitter user timeline without server side coding

Tags: javascript, twitter

I've been using this URL `https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=apolinariosteps&callback=twitterCallback2` but since twitter API 1.0 is now gone, and only 1.1 works, what should I do? 
I tried `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=apolinariosteps&callback=twitterCallback2`but it requires me authentication, I want to display always the same-user timeline in my application so it doesn't make sense to authenticate my user.

So I found this:https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth which I couldn't se a way to implement without server side coding, since I'm writing a PhoneGap app, I have no server choice.

What should I do to get to the user's timeline in API 1.1?

My code is

```
<ul id="twitter_update_list">

</ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/blogger.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=inagaki&callback=twitterCallback2"></script>
```

blogger.js grabs json and display it into nice `<li>`s 
What should I change to make this use the new authentication without server side coding?

Comment: You have to use Application-only auth, but you don't need server code to do so.

Comment: How could I achieve that then? I couldn't find a way to do so without server side coding.

Comment: To be fair I've used php last time to get this done, because there is a nice oauth plugin for php. But you might be right, it is really cumbersome to get it done only on the client side: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700106/twitter-oauth-authentication-in-javascript

Comment: I agree with @BalintBako, I had to use server side code, since oauth requires custom header with GET request (not AJAX), which is not easy to implement in javascript, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Use GET to retrieve the Json from the following URL and then parse it to get the required JSON attribute using javascript

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?

user_id : The ID of the user for whom to return results for.